# Unit test for MVVM with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, unit-testing

I recently started to add unit tests to my application (EF5, MVVM Light, .NET4.5), and [Effort](https://effort.codeplex.com/) works really nice for testing the Model. But I don't really know how to test the ViewModel with the fake DBConnection.

My context currently looks like this:

```
public partial class DataContext : DBContext
{
    // Gets used by the ViewModels
    public TraceContext() : base("name=DataContext") { }

    // Gets used by Effort for unit testing
    public TraceContext(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, true) { }
}
```

In my ViewModel it's used (simplyfied) in this way:

```
public IEnumerable<Measurement> Measurements { get { ... } set { ... } }

public void LoadData()
{
    // Get data always from a fresh context on reload,
    // to have most recent data from the database
    using (var context = new TraceContext())
    {
        Measurements = context.Measurements.ToList();
    }
}
```

And now the problem is that I don't really know how I should test the code above, with using the fake database.

```
[Setup]
public void SetUp()
{
    _viewModel = new MeasurementViewModel();

    // Only uses the DataContext connection string for EF magic
    // not to acctually connect to the database
    var connection =
        Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreateTransient("name=DataContext");

    _context = new DataContext(connection);

    // Insert test data
    ...
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

[Test]
public void TestLoadData()
{
    // Here comes the tricky part, how to tell the ViewModel
    // to use the fake Context?

    _viewModel.LoadData();
    Assert.IsNotEmtpy(_viewModel.Measurements);
}
```

Is there a good way to handle this without refactoring to much of my code?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to overload LoadData:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    // Get data always from a fresh context on reload,
    // to have most recent data from the database
    using (var context = new TraceContext())
    {
        LoadData(context);
    }
}

public void LoadData(TraceContext context)
{
    Measurements = context.Measurements.ToList();
}
```

In your Tests you can then call LoadData with the fake context:

```
[Test]
public void TestLoadData()
{
    _viewModel.LoadData(_context);
    Assert.IsNotEmtpy(_viewModel.Measurements);
}
```

A nicer way would be to work with factory methods or with factories...